# Displaying a list of similar but different objects without resorting to type checking

Tags: c#, blazor

I'm creating the UI for a "Point of Sale" type page. You can add orders, grouped orders, and custom items to your transaction, and it should display these in a list so you can see what you have selected.

They all have the same basic details:

- Type
- Description
- Price

But they also have major differences. E.g.

- Orders must show the items they contain
- Grouped orders (which are orders containing other others) must show the orders they contain
- Custom items also have a quantity that must be displayed

I'm struggling to find an elegant way to program this without just explicitly checking the type of each object.

This is pseudo-code for what I have currently:

```
foreach (ITransactionItem item in transaction.AllItems.OrderBy(x => x.AddedDateTime))
{
    <text>{item.Description}</text>
    <text>{item.Price}</text>
    <div>
        if (item is TransactionOrder)
        {
            // Show order items
        }
        else if (item is TransactionGroupOrder)
        {
            // Show child orders
        }
        else if (item is TransactionCustomItem)
        {
            // Show item quantity
        }
    <div>
}
```

I basically created an interface for the shared details, and then added everything into one list of this interface.

The big "if else" just feels wrong and I'm sure there is a better solution, but I can't think of it or find anything from searching. I can't delegate the display logic to the classes themselves because they are from a class library (they can't contain UI code). I also can't just loop over each type separately because they need to be ordered by when they were added to the transaction.

Any ideas or design patterns I'm missing? I'm writing this in Blazor if it has any relevance.

Comment: A Razor Class library can contain UI its not hard to convert an exising dll proj to a rcl if you have access to the source. Essentially the first line in the proj file... You could use a switch statement returning `RenderFragment`'s.

Comment: @BrianParker I can't/won't convert the library because it is the "Business Logic" layer and I don't want to mix it with UI layer dependencies. However, you did give me the idea to create my own version of the classes in the UI layer that can return a `RenderFragment`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a switch statement it handles type checking fairly elegantly.

```html
@FruitView
```

```cs
@code {
    Fruit fruit = new Orange();

    RenderFragment FruitView => fruit switch
    {
        Apple => AppleView,
        Pear => PearView,
        Orange => OrangeView,
        _ => throw new Exception("...")
    };

    // These could be a call to another component... 
    RenderFragment AppleView =>@:@{
        <div></div>
    }
;
    ...
}
```

Note how I have to place the `;` on a new line for the razor compiler.

Comment: I'm more concerned about avoiding checking types at all. This is effectively the same as my current if-else example.

Comment: Well you can't Blazor has no concept of MvvM. Reflection or Source generators are your choices.